# PHP_CodeSniffer not following provided external standard

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I've got an external standard, which I got out of Sonar. I specify the standard with the --standard=/path/to/standard.xml methodology. If that isn't a valid file, I get an error. So it is reading and parsing the file.

My problem is in the output it is including several sniffs that my standard isn't telling it to use. I get a ton of false positives going into Jenkins. Sonar at least strips out the ones that aren't in that standard. For instance, I've turned off all of the full stop rules, but they are still showing up in my report.

I am running PHP_CodeSniffer version 1.3.2.

Comment: Could you please attach your ruleset file? You might be including rules from other stndards...